# Detect FlatList onBeginningReached - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, jsx

I'm using a `<FlatList>` component to display a simple list.

This component has events for `onEndReached`, but I could not find an equivalent for the top, like an `onBeginningReached` event.

How do you detect that a user has scrolled to the very top of the `<FlatList>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onMomentumScrollEnd` prop for that purpose:

```
onMomentumScrollEnd={e => {
  if (e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y === 0) {
    // do things
  }
}}
```

I'm suggesting `onMomentumScrollEnd` and not `onScroll`, because it will fire far less often and will put less strain on the performance.

Comment: Thank you sir ! Exactly the solution I was looking for. works exactly as expected.

Comment: I guess there's an issue with `onMomentumScrollEnd` in android? check this [example](https://snack.expo.io/@anastely/gallery-ex) you will see